# AmChart component is not rendering (AIR app)

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

Our AIR app consists from multiple modules. Each module extends MovieClip class. But when I am adding AmChart component to one of these modules, it is not rendering. Here the sample (PieChart.mxml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:SkinnableContainer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
   xmlns:amcharts="http://www.amcharts.com/com_internal"
   width="100%" height="100%">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
   import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

   [Bindable]
   private var chartData:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
    {country:"Czech Republic",litres:156.90},  
    {country:"Ireland",litres:131.10},
    {country:"Germany",litres:115.80},  
    {country:"Australia",litres:109.90},  
    {country:"Austria",litres:108.30},  
    {country:"UK",litres:99.00},  
    {country:"Belgium",litres:93.00}]);
  ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <amcharts:AmPieChart width="100%" height="100%" dataProvider="{chartData}" titleField="country" valueField="litres"/>
</s:SkinnableContainer>
```

And this is a sample usage:
    var chart:PieChart = new PieChart();
    cContainer.addChild(chart);

```
cContainer - is instance of MovieClip.
```

Can you suggest why this is not rendering? Maybe this seems a silly question, but I am a quite newbie to Flex. Please, help.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try using the dataset syntax used here http://blog.amcharts.com/2010/11/amstock-flex-tutorial-part-1-basics.html, and also try using a number for width and height until you get it working, rather than a percentage.  If neither of those works, you may want to try asking the people who wrote this.

HTH;

Amy